# new Date to accept certain format in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have an api that return bunch of dates with this format

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

so when I try to do something with new Date()

`new Date('1/2/2017')` I got Jan 2, but in fact it means 1st of Feb. I can't change how the api is written, any workaround I can make new Date() take dd/mm/yyyy not mm/dd/yyyy?

I don't want to use library like moment.

Comment: You don't want jQuery for this. It's easy enough to switch the month with the day: `yourDate.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3")`. Or `.split("/")` and use the pieces with `new Date(year, month, day)`.

Comment: There's a getDateFromFormat() function that parse a date string and return time in ms representing date object http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/. Maybe that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the order of the date you currently have. The Date constructor will accept the format `yyyy/mm/dd`. It would also be easier than doing regular expressions:

```js
function getDate(date) {
  date = date.split('/').reverse().join('/');
  return new Date(date);
}

let date = '1/2/2017';

alert(getDate(date)); // Wednesday, February 1, 2017
```